# SQL Server 2014 displays right arrow symbol (->) with code

Tags: sql, database, ssms

[Please click this - weird characters displayed in SQL Server window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcpxB.png)

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I see these different type of special characters with code..  I searched about this but did not find anything.. Does anyone know how to disable this?

Thanks

Comment: Those are tabs and spaces. Edit --> Advanced --> View White Space

Comment: Resolved .Thank you.